# Why don't my beefalo produce much manure anymore?

Tags: dont-starve

Recently I installed the [All's Well with Maxwell](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/blog/new-update-alls-well-maxwell) update for Don't Starve.  Now I find (at least in brand new games) that my beefalo hardly produce any manure anymore.

When I find a beefalo herd, there's no manure around, and if I wait a while, four or five of them might produce just one or two between them in the course of a whole day.  Previously they used to be regular excrement factories.

This makes the game quite difficult, as manure is the limiting factor in producing farms.  (And it's a handy fuel as well.)

Is this a bug?  Is this intentional on Klei's part?  Is there any way I can fix it, short of waiting for the next update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we have an answer, straight from the beefalo's mouth, as it were:

[Beefalo not producing manure](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/index.php?/topic/29126-beefalo-not-producing-manure/?p=354791)

> Ah, talking with the designers, this is actually a tuning change that we put in.
>
> The Beefalo will now only produce manure when you are in the general vicinity of them. This is to prevent people from stumbling across Beefalo herds with huge amounts of manure sitting on the ground.

Comment: Not sure how I feel about this change, but at least now I know it wasn't my imagination.  I've found that I *do* get manure from the beefalo once I'm around them for a while.  It seems that if you set up camp nearby, they'll produce a decent amount...eventually.